# CSS loading through network tab status 200 no CSS is rendering on page

Tags: html, css

I ran into this really odd problem cause I'm proficient with CSS. However, I have a CSS file that I'm trying to load in my PHP document and it's loading fine through the network tab but isn't loading it's css on the page.

Here is what I checked for:

1) filename was correctly spelled and there are no special characters, whitespace etc.
2) No errors in my console indicating the file didn't load properly.
3) I received a status of 200 on the file but when I go to preview the css file. It tells me "This request has no preview available"
4) Adblock is disabled.
5) I validated through CSS validator and no errors or warnings were returned.

I'm using PHP and JavaScript but have no redirects going anywhere in my code.

I'm trying to link this css file in my PHP document and my other css files work fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive-table.css"> <!-- my file is indeed called "responsive-table.css" and it is located within the CSS folder.
```

Here is my CSS that will not load. It has 200 successful load on network tab but won't allow me to preview the file in the browser nor network tab. However, when I open the file there is code inside of it.

```
table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
th { 
    background: #333; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: normal; 
}
td, th { 
    padding: 6px; 
    text-align: left; 
}

.iconcontainer {
width:100%;
}

.smart-icon {
float:left;
padding-right:2%;
max-width:75px;
max-height:72px;}
/*
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media
only screen and (max-width: 768px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background: #ededed; 
    }

    td {
        border: none;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 39% !important;
        width:58% !important;
    }

    td:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size:11px;
        font-style:italic;
        opacity:0.6;
    }
    .SHOPPING-wrapper table tr.titlebox {
        background:#fff;
        border:0;
    }
    .SHOPPING-wrapper table tr.titlebox td {
        padding-left:5px !important;
    }
    .SHOPPING-wrapper table tr.titlebox td::before {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .SHOPPING-wrapper table tr.gray {
        display:none !important;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    #metro td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    #metro td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Route"; }
    #metro td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Telephone"; }
    #metro td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Website"; }

    #taxis td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Service"; }
    #taxis td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Telephone"; }

    #ferries td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    #ferries td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Location"; }
    #ferries td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Telephone"; }
    #ferries td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Website"; }
}
```

Comment: What is it that tells you "This request has no preview available"? The message doesn't look familiar. What do you see when you load the css file into the browser?

Comment: I found out what the issue was. Something was wrong in my CSS code that wasn't working so the entire document wasn't loading. Thanks